# Replace values inside list

Tags: jq

I have the following object :

```json
{
    "db_credentials": {
        "database": "greengrass",
        "host": "localhost",
        "password": "yZqXJzXHLUsLlPm",
        "port": 7086,
        "username": "greengrass"
    },
    "default_interval": 90000,
    "fields_selected": [
        {
            "measurement": "ABPLCGD-GD_AB1AirFlowCalc",
            "aggregation": "last",
            "step": "10m",
            "timeserie_physical": "null",
            "timeserie_type": "null",
            "timeserie_interpolation": "null",
            "timeserie_unit": "null",
            "timeserie_step": "10"
        },
        {
            "measurement": "ABPLCGD-GD_AB1InletAirTempAct",
            "aggregation": "last",
            "step": "10m",
            "timeserie_physical": "null",
            "timeserie_type": "null",
            "timeserie_interpolation": "null",
            "timeserie_unit": "null",
            "timeserie_step": "10"
        }
    ]
}
```

and i wish to transform it into :

```json
{
  "db_credentials": {
    "database": "greengrass",
    "host": "localhost",
    "password": "yZqXJzXHLUsLlPm",
    "port": 7086,
    "username": "greengrass"
  },
  "default_interval": 90000,
  "fields_selected": [
      {
        "name": "ABPLCGD-GD_AB1AirFlowCalc",
        "aggregation": {
          "step": "10m",
          "function": "last"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "ABPLCGD-GD_AB1InletAirTempAct",
        "aggregation": {
          "step": "10m",
          "function": "last"
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

i have tried multiple solution but this is the maximum where i can get :

```
 jq  ' .fields_selected = .fields_selected | map({name : .measurement , aggregation : {step: .step , function: .aggregation}})' config-it-client.json
```

but i got always this error that **Cannot index number with string "measurement"** and i cant figure out what i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the following:

```
.fields_selected[] |= { name: .measurement, aggregation: { function: .aggregation, step } }
```

---

To get it working, you were just missing parens.

```
.fields_selected = .fields_selected | ...
```

means

```
( .fields_selected = .fields_selected ) | ...
```

It should be

```
.fields_selected = ( .fields_selected | ... )
```

This gives us

```
.fields_selected = (
   .fields_selected |
   map({
      name: .measurement,
      aggregation: {
         function: .aggregation,
         step: .step
      }
   })
)
```

[Demo on jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/i_9x42fQZU)

---

But we can improve this. `foo = ( foo | ... )` can generally be written as `foo |= ( ... )`.

```
.fields_selected |= map({
   name: .measurement,
   aggregation: {
      function: .aggregation,
      step: .step
   }
})
```

We could modify the objects in the fields array instead of the array itself.

```
.fields_selected[] |= {
   name: .measurement,
   aggregation: {
      function: .aggregation,
      step: .step
   }
}
```

Finally, `{ foo: .foo, ... }` can be shortened to `{ foo, ... }`.

```
.fields_selected[] |= {
   name: .measurement,
   aggregation: {
      function: .aggregation,
      step
   }
}
```

As a sh one-liner:

```sh
jq '.fields_selected[] |= { name: .measurement, aggregation: { function: .aggregation, step } }'
```

[Demo on jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/R8WCZ2LG1Q)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out what i was doing wrong:

```
jq  '.fields_selected = (.fields_selected | map({name : .measurement , aggregation : {step: .step , function: .aggregation}}))' config-it-client.json
```

Comment: You can further shorten it to `jq '.fields_selected |= map({name: .measurement, aggregation: {step, function: .aggregation}})' config-it-client.json`

Comment: @pmf, You can even remove `map()` by using `.fields_selected[]`

Comment: @ikegami i updated the result juste now soory for the mistake